For what $A$ can the function $\sin(x)+\sin(x+A)$ be expressed by $\sin(x+B)$ for any real number $B$?
I thought of this question while playing around with Desmos when I found their Trigonometry: Wave Interference example. I saw that most of the results could not describe a unit circle (e.g., $\sin x$ is always multiplied by some constant). I learned about trigonometry from YouTube, so I only have a basic grasp of what the functions do. By brute force, I found A to be approximately $2.094$ and found B to be about $1.047$. Any explanations on how one would solve this problem would be helpful.

$\sin(x)+\sin(x+A)=2\cos\left( \frac{A}{2}\right) \sin\left(x+\frac{A}{2}\right)$

You want $\sin(x) + \cos(A) \sin(x) + \sin(A) \cos(x) = \cos(B) \sin(x) + \sin(B) \cos(x)$.  For this to be true for all $x$, you need $1 + \cos(A) = \cos(B)$ and $\sin(A) = \sin(B)$.  Now $\sin(A) = \sin(B)$ implies $\cos(A) = \pm \cos(B)$.  $\cos(A) = \cos(B)$ obviously doesn't work, so we try $\cos(A) = -\cos(B) = -(1+\cos(A))$, which implies $\cos(A) = -1/2$ and $\sin(A) = \sin(B) = \pm \sqrt{3}/2$.  It works when
$A = 2\pi/3 + 2 n \pi$ or $4 \pi/3 + 2 n \pi$ where $n$ is an integer.
